# Get current ArrayList length after removing an element in onBindViewHolder()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

How do I get the current ArrayList length after removing an element from it?

I have a fragment that contains a `RecyclerView`. In the adapter I delete the respective element in the list in the `onBindViewHolder()` by clicking on an icon - everything works wonderfully.

But after removing an element, I need the array length in my fragment.

How do I get this, what method do I need to call from the `onbindViewHolder()`?

Adapter Code:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val cR = context.contentResolver
    val type = cR.getType(listeImg[position])


    if(type.toString().contains("mp4"))
    {

        val con = MediaController(context)

        con.setAnchorView(holder.imageForList)
        con.setMediaPlayer(holder.playing)


        holder.playing.setOnPreparedListener {it->
            it.setVolume(0F,0F)
            it.isLooping =  true


        }
        holder.playing.keepScreenOn = true
        holder.playing.setVideoURI(listeImg[position])
        holder.playing.start()
        holder.playVideo.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        holder.playing.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    else
    {
        if(listeImg.size == 0)
        {
            holder.delete.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
        else if(listeImg.size > 0)
        {
            holder.delete.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        }
        holder.playing.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        holder.playVideo.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

        Glide.with(context).load(listeImg[position]).placeholder(R.drawable.no_image)
            .skipMemoryCache(false)
            .into(holder.imageForList)
    }
    
    holder.delete.setOnClickListener {
        listeImg.removeAt(position)
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position,listeImg.size)

    }
    
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return listeImg.size
}
```

Comment: please attach adapter code.

Comment: i have done....

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to get the list size of your data which is added to recyclerView. you can create your list at the top of the fragment class, and initialize it with your list of where come from. then you can access this from all of your fragment.

also, you achieve it like this, create this method in your adopter.

```
fun getListSize(): List<YourListType> {
    return listeImg.size
    notifydatachanged()
}
```

then call it from your fragment. like ( yourAdopter.getListSize())

Comment: Ok and when do I call this method? For example, I want to show the number of elements in the array. After deleting in the adapter, the number in the fragment should of course also be reduced. When do I call the method from the adapter for this?

Comment: I update my answer related your the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first call

linkeimg.remove(getAdapterPosition());

than call

notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());

notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(),mDataSet.size());

Answer (score 0):

try like this using higher-order function.

```
class ExampleAdapter(
    val updatedListSize: (Int) -> Unit
): RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder>(){
    
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int){
        // after removing data from list
        updatedListSize.invoke(listeImg.size)
    }
}
```

and in fragment you can do something like below

```
val adapter = ExampleAdapter(){ updatedListSize ->
   // do updated operations
}
```

Comment: Isn't it all automated? Simply because when I called notifyItemRangeChanged() I get the ArrayList length in my fragment?

Answer (score 0):

First you remove a item and notified the array list then down code is used

```
adapter = SearchMerchantsAdapter(listData,::checkCurrentListSize) // This code is Fragment Adapter Code

class SearchMerchantsAdapter(var dataList: ArrayList<GlobalSearchItemData>,private val getCurrentListSize: (Int) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MerchantsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        getCurrentListSize(dataList.size)
    }
}

fun checkCurrentListSize(i: Int) { // This Fun Use High Order Funtion through data get (checkCurrentListSize) fun name use in Adapter Call Line
    Log.d("checkArraySizeGet", i.toString())
}
```